# Memory building up (no leaks detected) using Spritebuilder

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm not very good at memory management, so I'll start with that as my disclaimer, but I did try to find out as much as I could about my current problem. I'm using Spritebuilder to make an app (uses cocos2d) and whenever I switch between two scenes I'm getting a slow memory build up in my game. I am looking at the "Memory" tab under the Debug Navigator.

Now I created a new project in Spritebuilder to see if a new app would also have this problem. It didn't. So clearly there is something going on in mine specifically.

I tracked it down a little further. One of the scenes in my game I'm switching to is just a simple menu screen with a couple CCButtons, and the other is a larger scrollable level map with many CCButtons, many textures...etc. Clearly the memory would always build up when I switched back to the more complex level scene. I have about 60 CCButtons on that level scene, and decided to remove them all and do the same test. This time, with all CCButtons removed, I did not see a memory build up (or at least it was building up at 1/100 the amount every time I switched). So I think that is the main cause of this memory build up - the way I'm allocating memory for my buttons.

I opened up the instruments tool in Xcode and looked for leaks, but did not find any (not super good at using this, but it seemed somewhat straightforward). So I feel like I am just allocating memory that is maybe not necessary?

Also, I'm not too sure what the Memory tab exactly means. Is it a problem if this builds up as I use my app more and more? Below is the method I use to initialize a button within my level scene.

```
-(void)createButtonAt:(CGPoint)buttonLocation buttonTitle:(NSString*)buttonTitle buttonNumber:(int)buttonNumber{

    tempButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:buttonTitle
                                             spriteFrame:redTile
                                  highlightedSpriteFrame:redTile
                                    disabledSpriteFrame:nil];

    tempButton.label.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0];
    tempButton.block = ^(id sender) {
        for (int i = 1; i < buttonNumber; i++) {
            [[LevelManager sharedInstance] nextLevel];
        }
        levelNumber = i;
        [self loadMyViewController];
    };
    tempButton.scale = 0.3
    tempButton.label.fontName = @"HelveticaNeue-Bold";
    tempButton.label.fontSize = 34;
    tempButton.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    tempButton.position = buttonLocation;
    [self addChild:tempButton];
    [buttonArray addObject:tempButton];
}
```

When first loading the game I would be at 14 MB. After loading all of my levels and scenes, I would be around 60 MB. Then every time I played a level after that, the memory would increase 6-7 MB. Is this a problem? Please let me know if there is a specific reason this is happening, or some resources for how to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i recall, i think that the issue is with `setBlock` which causes a retain cycle. Try this:

```
__weak id _weakSelf = self;
tempButton.block = ^(id sender) {
    for (int i = 1; i < buttonNumber; i++) {
        [[LevelManager sharedInstance] nextLevel];
    }
    levelNumber = i;
    [_weakSelf loadMyViewController];
};
```

obcit: from memory, not tested, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me onto the retain cycle. I commented out the block and reran my project and low and behold... the memory buildup disappeared. So that appears to be the culprit. Unfortunately though, copying your code block into my project didn't help things. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: hmmm ... not certain where to take it from here. the __weak ref solved it for me. Before i did that, i used to set each CCControl's block property to nil in a convenient place ( onExit in my case, but will only be invoked when the node is removed from its parent).